# why it is not able to obtain Heap dump in Alpine docker with pid as 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a java application with pid as 1.
we were trying to get the heap dump. The application is running in docker.
The base image is alpine:latest

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof 1
1: Unable to get pid of LinuxThreads manager thread

tried 
jcmd 1 GC.heap_dump dump.hprof
1:
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to get pid of LinuxThreads manager thread
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:86)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
```

```
ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      2:16 {java} thejavaprogram
   52 root      0:00 sh
  309 root      0:00 ps
```

please help me.

Comment: any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/76